# Does KMP algorithm perform less comparisons than the simplified Boyer-Moore algorithm?

Tags: string-search, boyer-moore

Does the KMP (Knuth–Morris–Pratt) algorithm perform fewer comparisons than the simplified Boyer-Moore algorithm?

Comment: I did some tests on these many years ago. B-M won every time over KMP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Boyers Moore algorithm should usually perform with less comparisons to quote from [here](http://www.macs.hw.ac.uk/~alison/ds98/node78.html)

> It should be reasonably clear that, if it is normally the case that a given letter doesnt appear at all in the search string, then this algorithm only requires approx N/M character comparisons (N=length(s1), M=length(s2)) - a big improvement on the KMP algorithm, which still requires N. However, if this is not the case then we may need up to N+M comparisons again (with the full version of the algorithm). Fortunately, for many applications we get close to the N/M performance. If the search string is very large, then it is likely that a given character WILL appear in it, but we still get a good improvement compared with the other algorithms (approx N*2/alphabet_size if characters are randomly distributed in a string).